# Phonegap - Open Links in Browser except embedded Videos

Tags: iphone, cordova, hyperlink, webview, external

I'm Developing an App using Phonegap, target Devices are Android or iOS driven. My Problem is, that on the iPhone I can only set the "open all whitelist urls in webview" parameter to true or false. So that is the Problem:

Expected Result: 
- All links (like www.google.com, www.stackoverflow.com) should open in the Browser
- An embedded iFrame with a Youtube Video should open in the Webview

Result with "OpenAllWhitelistUrlsInWebview" Set to true
- All links and iFrames will open in the Webview

Result with "OpenAllWhitelistUrlsInWebview" Set to false
- No links and iFrames will open in the Webview

How can i specify which links should open in the Browser and which shouldnt? When i remove an url from the whitelist the link won't open at all and also setting target="_blank" wont work properly. Trying it with window.open didn't work either.

Thank you very much for every idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented this over the weekend, and it's working great:
http://www.rigelgroupllc.com/blog/2012/05/22/opening-links-in-phonegap-apps-in-mobile-safari/

This will allow you to set up your plist for the youtube video, while using the above method to open specified links in the external browser.

I'm not sure what/if you need to do anything in Android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally solver it with a little variation of this. Every URL starting with http:// will open in the browser. The embedded youtube link will still open in the webapp.

Comment: @MichaelKunst - would you consider marking this as the answer, as it pointed you in the right direction for your final solution?

Comment: That tutorial is using hash anchoring to find the external URL. Here, we are loosing the hash anchoring in the URL. Do we have any other better way.